# How can I get both tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
<span class="sort-text">Dominus Estate</span> Napa Valley
```

```
name_list = []

name_tags = soup.find_all("class","sort-text")

for name in name_tags:

    name = name.get_text()

    name_list.append(name)

print(name_list)
```

`Dominus Estate`

but I want the following:

`Dominus Estate Napa Valley`

Comment: It's unclear what the input HTML looks like. Can you please edit your question and format the HTML correctly?

Comment: Please show what the encloses the span element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with [`.next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to get the text after the `span` and concat both strings:

```
name_tags = soup.find_all('span',{"class","sort-text"})
for name in name_tags:
    name = f"{name.get_text()} {name.next_sibling.get_text(strip=True)}"
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<span class="wineName">
    <span class="sort-text">Dominus Estate</span> Napa Valley 
    <span class="vintageNumber">2018</span> 
    <span class="plus">+</span>
    <span class="minus">-</span>
</span>
<span class="wineName">
    <span class="sort-text">Château Pichon Longueville Lalande</span> Pauillac 
    <span class="vintageNumber">2018</span> 
    <span class="plus">+</span>
    <span class="minus">-</span>
</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
name_list = []
name_tags = soup.find_all('span',{"class","sort-text"})

for name in name_tags: 
    name = f"{name.get_text()} {name.next_sibling.get_text(strip=True)}"
    name_list.append(name)

print(name_list)
```

###### Output

```
['Dominus Estate Napa Valley', 'Château Pichon Longueville Lalande Pauillac',...]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i didn't find that in the documentaion of bs4. But how did you find all the HTML code of the page

Comment: Added a [link to the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to my answer - Loving wine and using google I found the website and copied some HTML from the source code for that example. To get all the HTML I assumed you already work with `requests`.